# How do I set the velocity of an object in the direction of the game object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, velocity, direction

I want my ball to teleport to another teleporter and launch itself out of it directly forwards, in the direction the teleporter is facing.

I transform the position of the ball and try and reset the velocity but the ball barely moves out of the teleporter

```
 ball.velocity = linkedTeleporter.transform.forward * ball.velocity;
```

Where linkedTeleporter is a game object and ball is a rigidbody

Comment: Have you tried to store the balls velocity in a temporary variable

Comment: Yes no luck there

Comment: Try debugging what the actual ball.velocity is or if its a set amount then add that to the velocity instead of setting it to the balls velocity

Comment: So the ball drops and it's velocity is (0,-6.2), it's supposed to pop out of a teleporter thats at angle of 30 degrees, wouldn't adding the velocity just make it head down more as opposed to in the direction of the teleporter?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to multiply the teleporter forward vector by the ball *speed* (i.e. no direction, just a value).

Comment: If i switch ball.velocity to 10,100 or even 1000 the ball still just fumbles a bit and doesn't move

Comment: @4324 what velocity has your ball before it enters teleport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `ball.velocity` is a `Vector3`:

```
ball.velocity = linkedTeleporter.transform.forward * ball.velocity.magnitude;
```

Keep in mind that `.forward` is a reference to the blue Z-axis.  If you're in a 2D game, you probably want `.right` (red X-axis)